# How to capture values of checkboxes using Viewstate

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I have 2 checkboxes, one is called the approve and the other one reject. The purpose of each of the checkboxes is:
1. When the Approve checkbox is checked the comments need to be filled in and same is the case with the Reject checkbox. (These comments are saved in a History grid on the same page)
2. When both approve and reject have been unchecked: (this is the case when the user decides to change his/her mind and unchecks the approve checkbox and save, then the approve should delete all the previous approve comments and upon selecting the reject option, it should delete the last updated reject comments only. I have the logic for both of them and they work fine individually, but when both of them are used at the same time, only reject unchecked option works.
Please note that, Oracle database is used for backend.
Here's the code:

On page_load:

```
if (!this.cbReturn.Checked && !this.cbApproved.Checked)
{
    ViewState["Return"] = null;
    ViewState["Approve"] = null;
}
```

On approve_checkchanged

```
ViewState["Approve"] = cbApproved.ToString();
```

On Submit_click

for approve uncheck:

```
if (!this.cbReturn.Checked && !this.cbApproved.Checked)
{
     cReporter_Review = "N";

    string tRow = "";
    if (ViewState["Approve"] != null)
        tRow = ViewState["Approve"].ToString();
    else
        tRow = this.radTBAcceptComments.Text;

    DbServices dbService = new DbServices();

    string connectionString = dbService.Connection.ConnectionString;

    string querystring = "Delete from HSIP.FY_ST_QUESTION_COMMENTS_INFO q where q.state_code = " + strStateCode + " and q.record_type='Y' and q.display_number= " + numDisplayNumber + " and q.FY='2015'";



    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(querystring, connection))
        {

            connection.Open();

            DataSet ds = dbService.GetDataSet(querystring, CmdType.SQL);
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

      btnNextQue_Click(this, new EventArgs());

}
```

Please let me know if I have to add anything else to the viewstate. I have approve query only, for reject it works, so I didn't post the code. Please let me know the condition which needs to be added so that on approve check changed (when unchecked and also reject unchecked) it should enter into this part of the logic currently the breakpoint doesn't hit through the above logic for approve. Please help me with the condition.

Thanks,
Dimpy

Comment: Why do you need to "capture" the state of the CheckBoxes and store them manually in the ViewState? Just using the Checked property is not enough?

Comment: I am using viewstate to capture values for 2 states here: 1. When user unchecks approve (now both approve reject unchecked) and saved. 2. When user unchecks reject ( again both approve reject unchecked). How do I differentiate between both of them? Looking for a condition to separate both these cases. Hope this answers your point. Thanks

Comment: You always have access to the Checked property of the CheckBoxes. The state is already stored there.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more. So, if viewstate is removed then how do I capture the checkbox states on page_load ? I have never passed 2 variables on viewstate at the same time before. So, any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the Page_Load of the page that contains the 2 CheckBoxes? If so, you can get the Checked property of each CheckBox on each postback. Maybe I am missing something...

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion. this is the scenario: I have 2 checkboxes approve and reject. Upon the selection for each of these, a text box is available for comments to fill in. 1. The page loads with the previous user selection and this part works fine. When the user unchecks the previous selection and saves the page with no selection then the above logic should kick in (submit_click event from my original post) How do I achieve this? Please point me in the right direction. Thanks again for your quick reply